# Trying to make a remind command with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to create a remind command in Discord.py, and I have it nearly finished, I am just running into an issue with the task that searches the reminder database (MongoDB), and retrieves reminders that are expiring to DM the author. Here is my full code for this command and task:

```py
class remind(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.reminder_task.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.reminder_task.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
    async def reminder_task(self):
        data = collection.find({}).to_list(length=None)
        # async for i in data:
        for reminder in data:
            now = datetime.now()
            remindme = str({reminder['time']})
            remind = datetime.strptime(remindme, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            if now >= remind:
                guild = self.client.get_guild(remind['GuildID'])
                member = guild.get_member(remind['author_id'])
                await member.send(f"Reminder: `{remind['msg']}`")



    @slash_commands.command(name="remind", description="create a reminder!", options=[Option("time", "time until I remind you", Type.STRING, required=True), Option("reminder", "what should I remind you about?", Type.STRING, required=True)], guild_ids=bonbot_support)
    async def remind(self, ctx, time, reminder):
        time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400, "w": 604800}
        remindseconds = int(time[0]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]
        remindertime = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=remindseconds)
        author_id = ctx.author.id
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
        if ctx.author.bot:
                return

        rem_info = {"author_id": author_id, "GuildID": guild_id, "time": remindertime, "msg": reminder}

        await collection.insert_one(rem_info)
        await ctx.send('Reminder was set!')


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(remind(bot))
```

The error I can't get rid of is as follows:

```
    remindme = str({reminder['time']})
TypeError: '_asyncio.Future' object is not subscriptable
```

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `data = collection.find({}).to_list(length=None)` with `data = await collection.find({}).to_list(length=None)` because you try to use future object.

Comment: For some reason that gives me:
"discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.remind' raised an error: SyntaxError: cannot assign to await expression (remind.py, line 40)"

Comment: Oh, that is my error. I have edited my answer. See it and try again, please.

Comment: that did it! thanks so much!